# What is the size of a JavaScript reference?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory

for example:

```
function test (some_object) {
   return some_object;
}
```

Since objects are passed by reference, what would be the size of `some_object`?

How many bytes would it be?

Also, is there a way to run this code in the console and use the debugger to look at memory usage in Chrome Developer tools?

Comment: Sure, look at `performance.memory`. Also, the size of the reference depends on what platform v8 is targeting as it writes code directly to assembly.

Comment: `MemoryInfo {jsHeapSizeLimit: 793000000, usedJSHeapSize: 10000000, totalJSHeapSize: 18200000}` - what are these numbers for, how do they relate to the code I pasted above?

Comment: What are you actually measuring and why?

Comment: Are you asking if the size of an object changes if you pass it into a function as a parameter?

Comment: I'm asking about the size of an object reference, not the object itself.  I was just using the function above as an example.  I was hoping one of the debuggers would give this info.